# How to read password from properties file and use it build.gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have in my build.gradle the following:

```
signingConfigs
   release {
            storeFile file('/Users/name/testproject/test')
            storePassword getProps("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias = 'test'
            keyPassword = getProps("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
        }
```

```
def getProps(String propName) {
    def propsFile = rootProject.file('secrets.properties')
    if (propsFile.exists()) {
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
        return props[propName]
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

And in `secrets.properties` file I have password of keystore, but I am getting this when I try to build release APK:

`Cannot recover key`

Answer (score 0):

I tend to load the secret folder with all the contents, to begin with, and define an alias, then use that object to refer to all the defined passwords in the `secrets` file.

At the beginning of the **build.gradle** file:

```
def secrets = new Properties()
file("../secrets.properties").withInputStream {
    stream -> secrets.load(stream)
}

fileTree("../secrets").matching {
    include "**/*.properties"
}.each {
    File file ->
        file.withInputStream {
            stream -> secrets.load(stream)
        }
}
```

then where I need it:

```
release {
    // ...
    key = secrets.MY_KEY
}
```